# C++17 UTF8 std::string to std::wstring UTF32 using unicode.org code or C++ standard functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, unicode, c++17, wstring

Looking for a working solution to the classic UTF8 to UTF32 in a stable and tested system.

Now I have the source to Unicode.org's

C code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/id3lib/+/master/unicode.org/ConvertUTF.c
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/id3lib/+/master/unicode.org/ConvertUTF.h
License:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/id3lib/+/master/unicode.org/readme.txt

Using the following C++ which interfaces the C library code from above:

```
 std::wstring Utf8_To_wstring(const std::string& utf8string)
    {
        if (utf8string.length()==0)
        {
            return std::wstring();
        }
        size_t widesize = utf8string.length();
        if (sizeof(wchar_t) == 2)
        {
            std::wstring resultstring;
            resultstring.resize(widesize, L'\0');
            const UTF8* sourcestart = reinterpret_cast<const UTF8*>(utf8string.c_str());
            const UTF8* sourceend = sourcestart + widesize;
            UTF16* targetstart = reinterpret_cast<UTF16*>(&resultstring[0]);
            UTF16* targetend = targetstart + widesize;
            ConversionResult res = ConvertUTF8toUTF16(&sourcestart, sourceend, &targetstart, targetend, strictConversion);
            if (res != conversionOK)
            {
                return std::wstring(utf8string.begin(), utf8string.end());
            }
            *targetstart = 0;
            return std::wstring(resultstring.c_str());
        }
        else if (sizeof(wchar_t) == 4)
        {
            std::wstring resultstring;
            resultstring.resize(widesize, L'\0');
            const UTF8* sourcestart = reinterpret_cast<const UTF8*>(utf8string.c_str());
            const UTF8* sourceend = sourcestart + widesize;
            UTF32* targetstart = reinterpret_cast<UTF32*>(&resultstring[0]);
            UTF32* targetend = targetstart + widesize;
            ConversionResult res = ConvertUTF8toUTF32(&sourcestart, sourceend, &targetstart, targetend, lenientConversion);
            if (res != conversionOK)
            {
                return std::wstring(utf8string.begin(), utf8string.end());
            }
            *targetstart = 0;
            if(!resultstring.empty() && resultstring.size() > 0) {
                std::wstring result = std::wstring(resultstring.c_str());
                return result;
            } else {
                return std::wstring();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            assert(false);
            return L"";
        }
        return L"";
    }
```

Now this code initially works however crashes soon after due to some issues in the above interfacing code. This interfacing code was adapted from open source code found on GitHub from a production project...

However crashes a few strings into the conversion, so I guess there's a overflow in this code

Does anyone have a good replacement or example code for a simple C++11/C++17 solution to convert a std::string to std::wstring to get UTF32 unicode values encoded

Comment: Many libraries there are for this, why not use one like this https://github.com/contour-terminal/libunicode or borrow code from one of them.

Comment: [`std::wstring_convert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert) supports conversions between UTF-8 and UTF-32. However, it has been deprecated in C++17 onward, with no replacement in sight yet. But it still works.  Otherwise, you will have to use an external Unicode library, such as ICONV, ICU, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have a working solution for UTF8 to UTF16 using C++17 Locale:

This seems to do the job for me to convert to the correct level of Unicode to enable extraction of character codes to int to load glyph codes correctly

```
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <string>

std::wstring Utf8_To_wstring(const std::string& utf8string)
{
    wstring_convert<codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>> converter;
    wstring utf16;
    try {
        utf16 = converter.from_bytes(utf8string);
    }
    catch(range_error e)
    {
        // log / handle exp      
    }
    return utf16;
}
```

Comment: The question asked for UTF-32, not UTF-16. Or at least, it asked for a solution that works for wchar_t, which varies between platforms.

Comment: Yeah just no codecvt_utf8_utf32 in Locale or Boost.Locale yet so currently only core standard solution for those who find this. This will not be marked as solution. I will seek a proper UTF32 solution and have registered to Unicode Consortium also to query them  

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8_utf16

Comment: "*have registered to Unicode Consortium also to query them*" The Unicode Consortium manages the Unicode standard. They have nothing to do with any particular programming language's implementation of said standard. They can't make C++ do anything; only the C++ committee can do that.

Comment: Also, `codecvt_utf8<char32_t>` works for conversion to UTF-32.